# Inserting data in two tables having primary and foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have two tables:

Table 1

- Column 1 : primary key (acts as foreign key in Table 2)
- Column 2 : foreign key (which is primary key in Table 2)

Table 2

- Col 1 : primary key (acts as foreign key in table 1)
- Col 2 : foreign key (which is primary key in table 1)

How do I insert data into these tables?

Comment: Make the FK column(s) nullable and do an update later on once you have obtained the correct value. Other than that there is no way. I would also caution you against this design, likely it is not thought out very well.

Comment: You don't need to have this cross reference, remove the foreign key (Column 2) from either one of the tables.

Comment: The question is why do you think you need this circular reference structure to begin with? It probably means that your database design is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of design won't work: the insert instruction in both tables would be locked to each other and, even if you make the foreign key in both table nullable as suggested in one comment (losing referential integrity in the process), the insert operation wouldn't be atomic causing potentially lots of problems.

It seems to me you're trying to implement a many to many relation between two tables, if that is the case you should design a 3 table relation in this way:

TableA

- PK_A
- Field1_A
- Field2_A
- etc...

TableB

- PK_B
- Field1_B
- Field2_B
- etc...

ConnectingTable

- PK_CT
- PK_A (as foreign key)
- PK_B (as foreign key)
- FieldX
- etc...

In this way you can connect two tables in a ManyToMany relation without cross referencing them

Comment: Not sure how you got from circular reference to many-to-many, and the insert + update can be atomic if wrapped inside an explicit transaction.

Comment: I don't understand the leap to this being about many-to-many either.

Comment: It seems to me [...] , if that is the case [...]
I saw this kind of approach multiple times by people using DB for the first times

Being true that an explicit transaction wraps two instructions an atomic operation, it shouldn't be used as a default options by default mindset and, not being exactly sure what the OP wanted to do, I didn't suggested it